# How to sort dataframe in month+year order?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, sorting

I am new to python, and I am trying to solve a problem sorting a df in month+year format, and my original data just looks like this:
(re edit: Sorry, after checking the original df, the month column is actually like: Aug, Jul, Jul, Jun. Not number format)

```
ID       year   month      ym
1        2018    Aug    Aug 2018
2        2018    Jul    Jul 2018
3        2019    Jul    Jul 2019
4        2019    Jun    Jun 2018
```

The way I figure out is ①split into two df according to year, and then ②sort month, finally ③merge them. But there're some problems:

for ①, I don't know how to do the split by groupby;

for ②, I tried to sort like this, it succeeds, but it looks like it's just temporarily sorted:

```
sort_order=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
df.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(df['month'], categories=sort_order, ordered=True)
df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

for ③, I worry that because it's temporarily sorted, it will be the original one at the moment I try to merge they two.

I believe there should be better ways to solve this. Could anyone give a hint, or point out is there anything I got wrong? Thx!!

Answer (score 3):

according to your example (assuming your dataframe named df) just do the following:

```
df = df.sort_values(["year", "month"])
```

and this is the result :

```
    year    month   ym
1   2018    7   Jul 2018
0   2018    8   Aug 2018
3   2019    6   Jun 2018
2   2019    7   Jul 2019
```

Edit request:

So to transform months string into number just do like this :
create a dictionnary :

```
months = {
    "Jun": 6, 
    "Jul":7 ,
    "Aug": 8, 
    ....
}
```

and so on,
then just create a function to transform a month into an integer like this:

```
def transform(month):
    return months[month]
```

then just apply it to your df

```
df["month"] = df["month].apply(transform)
```

and in this way you will have a dataframe with integers instead of strings in the month column

Comment: I added the assignement back to `df` as I think this is OP's main problem (*it succeeds, but it looks like it's just temporarily sorted*)

Comment: Thank you for sharing!! it helps a lot!! sorry but i still have one more question, i just checked that the month column actually isn't number format, it is like: Jun, Aug, Jun, July. In this way how can I convert them to number? thx in advance!

Comment: I have edited my answer , check it ( just transform months into integers like described above , and the apply the same process to sort it ,)

Comment: Thank you for your kindly answering again! After running I got the key error 7. does it mean I try to access a key that isn’t in a dic.? But running dic. and def. function are all fine. Is there any places I might be wrong? thx in advance!

Comment: it could be that the dictionnary you have created is missing some entries, to be sure run this command : " df.month.unique() " and show me the result so we can create a proper dictionnary

Comment: edit your answer and add the result there , cause it's not showing in the comments section

Comment: Thank you for your help! after running the command it shows: array([ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6]). there seems to be more than 1 space in front of each of them, other than 10&11&12. But in the dict. I didn't add any extra space.

Comment: can you please reload the datafram and then apply "df.month.unique()" , and paste the result here  before applying "df["month"] = df["month].apply(transform)" (because that method has already affected your df)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! it already passed! thank you so much!

Comment: your welcome my friend :) if you can  just mark the question (answer) as resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a composite string with `YYYY-mm`, then sort according to this sequence.

We first convert your column `ym` in `MMM YYYY` string format to datetime format by [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) then, use [`dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to format the date string in `YYYY-mm`.  This format string with year at the beginning followed by month is good for sorting in chronological order.

```
df['YYYY-mm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ym'], format='%b %Y').dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

df = df.sort_values('YYYY-mm')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)


   ID  year month        ym  YYYY-mm
3   4  2019   Jun  Jun 2018  2018-06
1   2  2018   Jul  Jul 2018  2018-07
0   1  2018   Aug  Aug 2018  2018-08
2   3  2019   Jul  Jul 2019  2019-07
```

Comment: yep, I can understand! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with date, I suggest you to work with a real `DatetimeIndex`

```
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['ym']).rename('datetime'))
print(df)

# Output:
            ID  year  month        ym
datetime                             
2018-08-01   1  2018      8  Aug 2018
2018-07-01   2  2018      7  Jul 2018
2019-07-01   3  2019      7  Jul 2019
2018-06-01   4  2019      6  Jun 2018
```

Now you can easily sort your dataframe

```
>>> df.sort_index(ascending=False)
            ID  year  month        ym
datetime                             
2019-07-01   3  2019      7  Jul 2019
2018-08-01   1  2018      8  Aug 2018
2018-07-01   2  2018      7  Jul 2018
2018-06-01   4  2019      6  Jun 2018
```

Filter your dataframe:

```
>>> df[df.index > "2018-06"]
            ID  year  month        ym
datetime                             
2018-08-01   1  2018      8  Aug 2018
2018-07-01   2  2018      7  Jul 2018
2019-07-01   3  2019      7  Jul 2019
```

Group by year:

```
>>>  df.groupby(df.index.year)['ID'].sum()
datetime
2018    7
2019    3
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

Comment: it makes sense! thank you for your help!